# x++ and ++x which can't be left value (lvalue) in c?

Tags: c++, c

Occasionally, i've been asked a trick question: `x++` and `++x` which can't be left value in c?   A lot of people tell me that `++x` can't because ++x's assemble code not return a register。I doubt it。 So i do some experiment。

c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    a++ = 10; 
    ++a = 10; 
    return a;
}
```

gcc compile error:

```
./test.c:6: invalid lvalue in assignment
./test.c:7: invalid lvalue in assignment
```

change the code and assembly:

```
int a = 1;
int b = a++; 
int c = ++a;
```

assembly code：

```
0x08048400 <main+0>:    push   %ebp
0x08048401 <main+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048403 <main+3>:    sub    $0x18,%esp
0x08048406 <main+6>:    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%ebp)
0x0804840d <main+13>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
0x08048410 <main+16>:   mov    %eax,-0x8(%ebp)
0x08048413 <main+19>:   incl   -0x4(%ebp)
0x08048416 <main+22>:   incl   -0x4(%ebp)
0x08048419 <main+25>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
0x0804841c <main+28>:   mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
0x0804841f <main+31>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%edx
0x08048422 <main+34>:   mov    %edx,%eax
0x08048424 <main+36>:   jmp    0x8048426 <main+38>
0x08048426 <main+38>:   mov    %ebp,%esp
0x08048428 <main+40>:   pop    %ebp
0x08048429 <main+41>:   ret
```

Seems the difference between ++x and x++ just comply with the semantic.Why lots of people say that ++a can be a left value but a++ can't?

Is there some issue i don't get? Or they are just nonsense?

After read Keith Thompson's answer, I guess in c++, x++ when x is a user define type cause postfix operator ++'s implemention(it's return a temporary object),so x++ can't be a lvalue.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class my_test
{
        int a;

public:
        void printf()
        {   
                cout << a << endl;
        }   


        my_test(int c)
        {   
                a = c;
        }    


        my_test& operator++()
        {   
                ++a;
                return *this;
        }   


        my_test& operator++(int)
        {   
                my_test temp(a);
                ++a;
                return temp;
        }   
};



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int a = 10; 
        int b = ++a;
        int c = a++;

        my_test obj1(1);
        my_test obj2(2);

        obj1++ = obj2;
        ++obj1 = obj2;

        obj1.printf();
        obj2.printf();

        return 0;
}
```

I use g++(version:g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)) compile the code,just get a warnning message.

```
[root@localhost ~]# g++ -g3 ./1.cpp -O0
./1.cpp: In member function 'my_test& my_test::operator++(int)':
./1.cpp:30: warning: reference to local variable 'temp' returned
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Seems in c++,++x and x++ both can be lvalue?

Comment: i had tried to compile your program , but it only gives warning to me `test.c:9:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   return 'a+b';`

Comment: This makes no sense unless `x` is a pointer, in which case `*x++` can be an lvalue, but `++*x` cannot. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10975666/1679849) for a better explanation.

Comment: Don't bother. What would be the practical use of incrementing `a` and also assign it another value?

Comment: Your original question was about C, and I answered it. If you want to ask about C++, please post a new question (or just consult a C++ reference).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term is *lvalue*, not "left value".

In  C, neither `x++` nor `++x` is an lvalue. This is because the language defines it that way; it has nothing in particular to do with assembly code.

(In C++, `++x` is an lvalue and `x++` isn't. Perhaps the source of your confusion.)

(You've updated your question to ask about overloaded `++` operators in C++. I already answered the original question. If you have a new question about a different language with different rules, please post it separately.)

Comment: @barcelona_delpy the result of `++x` if the updated `x`; the result of `x++` is a copy of the original value(not `x` itself), is not assignable. which compiler you try?

Comment: @barcelona_delpy: I'll bet your test code is incorrect.

Comment: @Keith Thompson,@zzn,i try with c++ built-in type int, use g++ compiler,++x and x++ both can be lvalue.  I figure out that when x is a user define type, x++ can't be a lvalue because postfix ++ operator's implementions:it return a temporary object。

Comment: @barcelona_delpy: `int x; x++ = 10;` produces an error from g++.

Comment: @Keith Thompson    I get it. tks.